# Xamarin.Forms: Display data to from 2 different tables to my User Interface

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, sql-server-2012, xamarin.forms

Good Day everyone. I'm currently creating an Xamarin.Forms application that allows me to CRUD record of an Employee. I want to have a User Interface that displays data that comes from 2 different table. I've used MSSql Server for my Database . Is it possible? How will I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible as long the tables share a common key(the Primary key). Look at this and hope it helps..
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716698(v=vs.100).aspx